# Caching solutions and Querying

Tags: java, caching, jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish

Are there any in-memory/caching solutions for java that allow for a form of Querying for specific attributes of objects in the Cache?

I realize this is something that a full blown database would be used for, but I want to be able to have the speed/performance of a cache with the Querying ability of a database.

Comment: How does what you're asking for differ from a simple Map? You can do rudimentary queries on a Map, restricted to one key returning one value.

Comment: To extend Paul's question, are your queries simple 'field = value' queries, or do you need more logic, like 'field > value' or 'field1 = value1 AND NOT field2 = value2'?

Comment: The more logic the better.  (field > x, y < field < x) like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays the answer should be updated to [Infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/), the successor of JBoss Cache and having much improved Search technology.

Comment: Yes, Infinispan make use of Apache lucene and Hibernate search for searching in cached objects.

Answer (score 4):

JBoss Cache has search functionality. It's called JBossCacheSearchable. From the site:

> This is the integration package
>   between JBoss Cache and Hibernate
>   Search.
>
> The goal is to add search capabilities
>   to JBoss Cache.  We achieve this by
>   using Hibernate Search to index user
>   objects as they are added to the cache
>   and modified.  The cache is queried by
>   passing in a valid Apache Lucene query
>   which is then used to search through
>   the indexes and retrieve matching
>   objects from the cache.

Main JBoss Cache page: http://www.jboss.org/jbosscache/

JBossCacheSearch: http://www.jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-10286

Answer (score 3):

[Terracotta](http://docs.huihoo.com/terracotta/TerracottaTreeCache.pdf) or [GBeans](http://www.jaxmag.com/itr/online_artikel/psecom,id,690,nodeid,147.html) or [POJOCache](http://www.samaxes.com/2009/03/jboss-pojocache-configuration/)

Comment: Ok, strange.  Somebody emailed me and told me to provide this link for pojocache: http://www.samaxes.com/2009/03/17/jboss-pojocache-configuration/?  I don't see why they wouldn't just make that comment here themselves.

Answer (score 2):

At first, [HSQLDB](http://www.hsqldb.org/) came to mind, but that's an in-memory relational database rather than an object database.  Might want to look at [this list](http://java-source.net/open-source/database-engines). There's a few object databases there, one of which might meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [db4o](http://db4o.org)at rather lightweight java object database. You can even query the data using regular java code:

```
List students = database.query( new Predicate(){
      public boolean match(Student student){
        return student.getAge() < 20
          && student.getGrade().equals(gradeA);}})
```

(From [this article](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=37595)).

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use Lucene and a RAMDirectory implementation of Directory to index what you put into your cache. That way, you can query using all the search engine query features which Lucene provides.

In your case, you will probably index the relevant properties of your objects as-is (without using an Analyzer) and query using a boolean equality operator.

Lucene is very lightweight, performant, thread-safe and memory consumption is low.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this library:

http://casperdatasets.googlecode.com

this is a dataset technology.  it supports tabular data (either from a database or constructed in code), and you can then construct queries and filters against the dataset (and sort), all in-memory.  its fast and easy-to-use.  MOST IMPORTANTLY, you can perform queries against ANY column or attribute on the dataset.